# i want to make 2 html select tags dependent. how do i do it?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

I have 2 select tags which will get information from database. 1 takes from product_category table and other takes from product. I want to make the products select tag depend on the product_category select tag. For Example I have 2 categories of Medicines 1 is capsules and other is tablets. I want the product select tag to display me the names of the capsules when i select capsules in the product_category select tag. how do i make it dependent? here is the code for those select tags.

```
<div class="form-group" style="width:50%;">
        <label>Select Category</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="product_category" id="product_category" >
            <?php 
            $query="SELECT * FROM product_category";
            $cat_result= mysqli_query($connection,$query);
            while($cat_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cat_result))
            {
              $ctg_id=$cat_row['category_id'];
              $ctg_name= $cat_row['category_name'];
              echo "<option value='$ctg_id'>$ctg_name</option>";
            }
            ?>    
        </select>
    </div>
   <div class="form-group" style="width:50%;">
        <label>Select Product</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="product_name" id="product_name">
            <?php 
            $query="SELECT product_id,product_name FROM product";
            $result= mysqli_query($connection,$query);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
              $product_id=$row['product_id'];
              $product_name= $row['product_name'];
              echo "<option value='$product_id'>$product_name</option>";
            }
            ?>    
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to get the data asynchronous, by using Ajax for example. Otherwise you need to submit the form, and process the rest on a different page/after reloading

Comment: http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/php_drop_down_list.php please refer this post here no way shown to populate drop downs - Hope it will help you

Comment: you can provide your both table data and structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using ajax its simple to load its product name in second select

> your main file code is below

```
<?php 
$connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","your database name");
?>
<div class="form-group" style="width:50%;">
        <label>Select Category</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="product_category" id="product_category" >
            <?php 
            echo  $query="SELECT * FROM product_category";
            $cat_result= mysqli_query($connection,$query);
            while($cat_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cat_result))
            {
              $ctg_id=$cat_row['category_id'];
              $ctg_name= $cat_row['category_name'];
              echo "<option value='$ctg_id'>$ctg_name</option>";
            }
            ?>    
        </select>
    </div>
   <div class="form-group" style="width:50%;">
        <label>Select Product</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="product_name" id="product_name">

        </select>
    </div>
```

download letest javascript library
https://jquery.com/download/

`script` code

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="path of .js library file"></script>   
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#product_category").change(function(){
                var id=$("#product_category").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    data:{id:id},
                    url:"ajaxcoderesponse.php",
                    success:function(result){
                        $("#product_name").html(result);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
     </script>
```

> your ajax file code

ajaxcoderesponse.php

```
<?php
    $connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","your database name");

    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $query="SELECT product_id,product_name FROM product where category_id=$id";
    $result= mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
      $product_id=$row['product_id'];
      $product_name= $row['product_name'];
      echo "<option value='$product_id'>$product_name</option>";
    }
?>
```

create `category_id` field in product table and give id of `product_category` table record

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, you need to use Ajax. When you select a product_category on success method you have to call the name of product_tag. This way you can use the ID of product_category to get the names of product tag .Use Jquery AJax ;)

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Firstly, fill the first select (Select Category). Create an event 'change' on this select and when the user select an option fill the other select with Ajax . Something like this:

```
$( "#product_category" ).change(function() {

 $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "some.php", /* The page you want */
    data: { id:  } /* here , you have to send the ID product category */ 
 }).success(data ) {
    /* Here you have to fill your new select with the info you have got it. If you selected capsules, the info you get it is the name of capsules*/
     $.each(data, function() { /* Iterator the object */
        $("#product_name").append("<option>" + data.value + "</option>")
     })

 })
});
```

Comment: any help with the code? I am not much familiar with AJAX  :(

Comment: it's not working :/ How should I get the names of products related to that category and show them in the new select?